# QGIS Action commands in 3.8

Tags: qgis-3, actions

In earlier versions i was able to open pdf files by using an action command like this one:

cmd /c [%path%]

this function no longer works on version 3.8. Any ideas why and what an alternative could be?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an absolute path to your pdf file, use:

```
cmd /c "path/to/myFile.pdf"
```

If you want to reference a field, use:

```
cmd /c [%myField%]
```

---

Both commands work with *Type* set to `Generic` or `Windows`.